# modifying a variable globally from a function in another file

Tags: python, python-2.7, function

My scenario is like
I have a script, and i have another function which will be running in an infinite loop in background. In this background function, I am modifying a variable.
I want  the main function to get the same variable's updated value..

```
 file name: kkk.py
 from junk import *
 a={1:2,3:4}
 test(a)
 print a ---> I want this to get modified from test() defined in the second file
 filename:junk.py
 from kkk import a
 import time

 def test(a):
 while(True):

    print 'inside the infinite loop'
    a={999:100}
```

I want modified value of a to reflect in kkk.py when I print a

The above code is throwing me error saying test(a) is not defined in kkk.py though i imported the test() properly.

can some one help me on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not working because of cyclic import both the files importing each other.

You can do following:

kkk.py

```
from junk import *
import common

print common.a
test(common.a)
print common.a
```

junk.py

```
import common
import time

def test(a):
        while(True):
                print 'inside the infinite loop'
                common.a={999:100}
                break
```

common.py

```
a={1:2,3:4}
```

Now if you execute python kkk.py, you will get below results.

```
{1: 2, 3: 4}
inside the infinite loop
{999: 100}
```

Note: I have added break in while loop for checking results.

Comment: But is this 'common'  part of standard libraries?

Comment: No, we have created common.py file and there added a variable so we are importing common file in both junk.py as well as kkk.py file.
This is general way when same variable is used by multiple files.

Answer (score -2):

try to modify global variable as shown below

```
globals()['a'] = 'Required value'
```

This will modify the global variable

Comment: Do I need to add from kkk import a in the second file? In this case my first file throws error.
With out this, the first file still has same 'a' value even after the globals() is called

Comment: do, from kkk import *

Comment: No luck

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Users/syam.mohan/PycharmProjects/cluster_busy/kkk.py", line      153, in <module>
        from junk import *
      File "/Users/syam.mohan/PycharmProjects/cluster_busy/junk.py", line 4,     in <module>
        from kkk import *
      File "/Users/syam.mohan/PycharmProjects/cluster_busy/kkk.py", line     155, in <module>
        test(a)
    NameError: name 'test' is not defined